# 3D-FFT to calculate the AoA in FMCW radar

Tags: fft, radar

I am trying to implement 3D-FFT on an IF signal to estimate range-velocity-angle. I was able to get the required results in range and doppler steps. However, when I am doing the angle FFT along the antennas, the range-angle map shows an object on the correct range but on the whole FOV, I tried this on 2 different datasets and it is the same. Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks in advance.

The dimensions of the datacube are as follows (# antennas x # chirps x # samples/chirp )

number of antennae: 4

number of chirps (L): 128

number of samples/chirp (N): 512

This is my code:

```
fr = (fs/2)*np.linspace(0,1,int(N/2))

for antenna in range(1,5):
    # range win processing
    sigRangeWin = np.zeros((4, L, N), dtype=complex)
    for l in range(0, L):
        sigRangeWin[antenna-1][l] = np.multiply(sigReceive[antenna-1][l], np.hamming(N).T)

    sigRangeFFT = np.zeros((4, L, np.size(fr)), dtype=complex)
    for l in range(0, L):
        fourier_m = np.fft.fft(sigRangeWin[antenna-1][l], n=N)
        sigRangeFFT[antenna-1][l] = (2/N)*fourier_m[0:np.size(fr)]

    ranges = freq_to_range(fr)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(ranges, abs(sigRangeFFT[antenna-1][0]))
    plt.show()      

    sigDopplerWin = np.zeros((4, L, sigRangeFFT.shape[2]), dtype=complex)
    for n in range(0, sigRangeFFT.shape[2]):
        sigDopplerWin[antenna-1, :, n] = np.multiply(sigRangeFFT[antenna-1, :, n], np.hamming(L).T)

    # doppler fft processing

    sigDopplerFFT = np.zeros((4, L, sigDopplerWin.shape[2]), dtype=complex)
    for n in range(0, sigDopplerWin.shape[2]):
        sigDopplerFFT[antenna-1, :, n] = 2.0/L*np.fft.fft(sigDopplerWin[antenna-1, :, n], n=L)

sigAngleWin = np.zeros((4, L, sigDopplerFFT.shape[2]), dtype=complex)
for l in range(0, L):
    for n in range(0, sigDopplerFFT.shape[2]):
        sigAngleWin[:,l, n] = np.multiply(sigDopplerFFT[:,l, n], ss.windows.taylor(4).T)

# Angle zero padded fft processing
plt.figure()
sigAngleFFT = np.zeros((128, L, sigAngleWin.shape[2]), dtype=complex)
for n in range(0, sigAngleWin.shape[2]):
    for l in range(0, L):
        sigAngleFFT[:, l, n] = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(sigAngleWin[:, l, n], n=128, axis=0))
        plt.plot(sigAngleFFT[:, l, n])
plt.show()

Xpow = abs(sigAngleFFT)
Xpow = np.squeeze(np.sum(Xpow, axis=1)/Xpow.shape[1])
Xsnr = np.transpose(Xpow)
ax = sns.heatmap(Xsnr)
```

The plot of each cell along the Rx dimension:

[image: The plot of each cell along the Rx dimension:]

Range-angle map

[image: Range-angle map:]]